# iOS dev --- how to handle mms:// protocol

Tags: ios, mms, libmms

I wanna play mms protocol audio, any idea about this? I heard libmms is a choice. But i do not know how. Anyone can share sample codes? it's better introduce from scratch.
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into the DocumentInteractionController here:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS.pdf  The Document Interaction Controller is the "Apple" way to do it and likely your safest path now and in future versions of the iOS.

If you own the file in your bundle you can get the default app to handle the file type from the OS:

```
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: fileName];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self getFileCompletePath]]){
    NSString *filePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [self getFileCompletePath]];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: url];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Not supported application to open the file %@", filePath);
    }

    [url release];
    [filePath release];
}
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two options:

1. Libmms: this library will only handle the mms protocol. So it's up to you to do whatever you want with the data.
2. FFmpeg: this library can handle the mms protocol and also has audio/video decoding capabilities. Since you'll be using the mms:// protocol for audio/video streaming, choosing FFmpeg will be a better choice.